# Amazon MWS for third-party app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm writing a script to get the order details using Amazon MWS. If I use all my credentials (SellerId, AWSAccessKeyId, and so on) all works fine. But I need the script to allow my customer to manage their orders, so I asked them [to fill this form](https://sellercentral.amazon.it/gp/mws/registration/register.html?*Version*=1&*entries*=0&signInPageDisplayed=1) to grant me access to their account as a developer. Than they passed me their SellerId and MWSAuthToken, but if I try to read the order details of one of their orders using their sellerID and token, I get this error:

*AccessDenied*

*AuthToken is not valid for SellerId and AWSAccountId.*

While if I use just their token, I get no error but the response is an empty xml with only the request ID.

Any Idea on how to manage it correctly?

Thanks!
Nadia

Answer (score 0):

You should be using their seller ID and the MWSAuthToken that they give you to make the request, along with your developer credentials.  If you're sure you are set up right, I would contact [MWS support](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html), they should be able to help figure out what is wrong.

Comment: It is what I did (using customer's data). I contacted the support, but they answered that my customers should, not me. Than didn't answer anymore.